# How to test string contains elements in list and assign the target element to another column via Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a one column list presenting some **company names**. Some of those names contain the country names (e.g., "China" in "China A1", 'Finland' in "C1 in Finland"). I want to extract their belonging countries based on the company name and a pre-defined list consisted of country names.

The original dataframe **df** shows like this

```
    Company name    Country
0   China A1        
1   Australia-A2        
2   Belgium_C1      
3   C1  in  Finland
4   D1  of  Greece
5   E2  for Pakistan
```

For now, I can only come up with an inefficient method. Here is my code:

```
country_list = ['China','America','Greece','Pakistan','Finland','Belgium','Japan','British','Australia']
for t in country_list:
    df.loc[df['company name'].contains(t),'country']=t
```

The result shows like

```
    Company name    Country
0   China A1        China
1   Australia-A2    Australia   
2   Belgium_C1      Belgium
3   C1  in  Finland Finland
4   D1  of  Greece  Greece
5   E2  for Pakistan Pakistan
```

I thought that when the country_list contains large amount of elements, i,e, countries, it would be time-consuming via loop method. Is there any simpler method to tackle with my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Country'] = df['Company name'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(country_list)+')')

       Company name    Country
0          China A1      China
1      Australia-A2  Australia
2        Belgium_C1    Belgium
3   C1  in  Finland    Finland
4    D1  of  Greece     Greece
5  E2  for Pakistan   Pakistan
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.extract` with `Regex`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
country_list = ['China','America','Greece','Pakistan','Finland','Belgium','Japan','British','Australia']

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df["Country"] = df["Company_name"].str.extract("("+"|".join(country_list)+ ")")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
           Company_name    Country
0      China A1              China
1  Australia-A2          Australia
2      Belgium_C1          Belgium
3       C1  in  Finland    Finland
4        D1  of  Greece     Greece
5      E2  for Pakistan   Pakistan
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) here:

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(country_list))
# pat-->'(China|America|Greece|Pakistan|Finland|Belgium|Japan|British|Australia)'
df['Country']=df['Company name'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `findall` in case you have more than one country name in one cell

```
df["Company name"].str.findall('|'.join(country_list)).str[0]
Out[758]: 
0        China
1    Australia
2      Belgium
3      Finland
4       Greece
5     Pakistan
Name: Company name, dtype: object
```