# How to find pattern and replace values in new column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column values with accesories and attachments and major. Now I want a new column where accesories and attachments go under accessories and Major with major. I used re.search but the results are showing none.

Here is the dataframe

```
id = {1,2,3,4}
product = {'coffee accessories','coffee attachments','coffee machine','toaster'}

id    product    
1     coffee accessories
2     coffee attachments
3     coffee machine
4     toaster
```

now I want the solution to be

```
id    product               category
1     coffee accessories    accessories
2     coffee attachments    accessories
3     coffee machine        major
```

I used re search

`def func(x):
    return re.search(r'\baccessories\b|\battachments\b','Accesories')
new_order['new'] = new_order['product'].apply(func)`

but Im getting error in category the values are none.

thanks in advance

Comment: You're not using `x` in `func`. And why `major`? You missed the relevant tag `pandas`.. (edited)

Comment: I think you want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278604/9698684

Comment: Oh yeah, I didnt use x. by using x it solved. thanks

Comment: Note that in pandas you can do `Series.str.extract(...)`, which is a little more convenient that this